# viewDidAppear equivalent on apple watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I'd like to start the app with an small animation (actually it is a sequence of images), however if start the animation on `willActivate` the app waits until the animation finishes and then display the app. I see that there is no didActivate, is there another way to detect that the app is already displaying? Like a notification for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment that state does not exist in apple watch. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/.